# Literal Ampersands in Azure Search Query String

Tags: c#, query-string, urlencode, azure-cognitive-search

I'm am trying to apply a filter on a faceted search in Azure Search.  Unfortunately, some of my client's search data contain an ampersand character like this:

```
&facet=client&$filter=client eq 'Dunn & Bradstreet'
```

Since the above example is part of a query string, the ampersand in `Dunn & Bradstreet` is an issue.

Escaping the ampersand as follows results in an error:

```
&facet=client&$filter=client eq 'Dunn %26 Bradstreet'
```

The error when using the Azure Search Explorer to test search queries is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Invalid expression: There is an unterminated string literal at position 34 in 'client eq 'Dunn '.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
    }
}
```

Is there some magical workaround for escaping the `&` symbol in strings that won't break Azure Search?

Comment: [Apparently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax) the escape character is `\\`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That's for Lucene syntax. The question is about OData filter syntax.

Comment: @PoorInRichfield What error did you observe? How are you sending the request -- .NET SDK, Search Explorer in the Azure portal, calling the REST API directly...? Please edit your question to provide more details. Thanks!

Comment: @Bruce Johnston I updated the question to reflect error message.  Putting a '\' in front of the ampersand did not resolve the issue.  

I suppose I could HTML encode the data when it's loaded into the search index so no ampersands exist in the data, but that would be less than idea.

Comment: And you've tried `&amp;` in the search string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Search Explorer. It encodes characters in the URL other than ampersand. If you encode the ampersand itself, Search Explorer double-encodes it. I've confirmed that if you encode the ampersand when calling the REST API directly, it works correctly.

I'll update this answer when the bug has been fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

**Update: we fixed the issue in Search Explorer**

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  I've verified that the REST API works when encoding the ampersand as `%26`.  (I swear this didn't work yesterday, but seems to be working today!)

Comment: The issue has been fixed in Search Explorer